# Syntax error: missing '{' before '.' in typedef struct

Tags: c

I have these instructions.
This in `.h`:

```
typedef struct 
{
    int level;  
    int max;        
    int trace;      
} trace_settings_type;
```

This in `.c`:

```
trace_settings_type trace_settings;
trace_settings.level = 1;
trace_settings.max = 400;
trace_settings.trace = 3;
```

The compiler results are:

```
error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '.'
error C2059: syntax error: '.'
```

But I don't understand what's wrong.

Comment: *Where* in your .c file is that code? Please show a proper [mre]

Comment: Did you include the .h file in the .c file?

Comment: The assignments need to be inside a function.

Answer (score 3):

You're attempting to perform assignments outside of a function.  Assignments are executable statements, and must be inside of a function.

What you really want however is to *initialize* `trace_settings`, which you do at the time it is defined:

```
trace_settings_type trace_settings = { 1, 400, 3 };
```

Comment: Designated initializers?